# Wordpress how to add Theme Installation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I bought theme via appthemes and now I see that for install it I have to upgrade WordPress?
Anyway to do it differently?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check The theme installation requirement from the documentation. Normally every theme has an instruction about **compatible WordPress** version. But I don't think there will be a problem with the updated WordPress version. Always try to use update version.